# Running sql scripts in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to run a .sql in MySQL workbench. For this, I choose: `File -> Run SQL script` option and finally provided the sql file name, in my case it is: `sql_script.sql`

However, when I run this, I got below message:

```
Preparing...
Importing sql_script.sql...
Finished executing script
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

As per this error message, it seems that it is expects to pass the credentials. I am not sure how to do this if my interpretation of this error message is correct.

Any information how to past this issue?

Comment: Are you already connected? What is the output of `select current_user();` Then give output of `show grants for root@localhost;` (don't show the password hash here). Also show the script you are running.

Comment: it seems you are sending password "(using password: YES)" are you sure it is correct one ?

Answer (score 2):

On the top menu, you can connect to your database using Database > Connect to database then you can enter your credentials.

[image]

Comment: I did it, however it is still give me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving the password blank. I had the same issue where I already connected to the database, entered my password, and saved it in the vault, but when running an SQL script it prompted me to enter the password, to which it would always give an access denied error. Leaving it blank worked.